# Не работает скрипт Vue

Tags: vue.js

Тем, кто разбирается во Vue. Походу, в методе где-то ошибка.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vue.js Pet Depot</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/app.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
<ol>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in box" v-on:click="action">The index of {{item}}-{{index}}</li>
</ol>
 </div>


<script >
let vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    box:['Banana', 'Apple','Coconut']
  },
  methods:
  function action(){
    this.box[0] = "Hair";
  }
})




</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> methods:
> function action(){
> ```

Ну и где ты такой синтаксис видел в js?

Тут должен быть объект, методами которого являются функции.

> ```
> v-on:click="action"
> ```

А тут скобок не хватает.

Comment: Ок, я это поправил, но получилось еще больше ошибок.

Comment: methods:{
function action() {
    this.box[0]="Hair";
  }
}

Comment: @Just_Илья, ну как бы такого синтаксиса тоже не существует... `function`-то удали.

Comment: Хорошо,у меня все работает без багов, ножелаемого результата я так и не получил. Я ведь хотел при клике на таблицу, чтобы слово Banana заменялось на слово Hair.

Comment: @Just_Илья, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий пример на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/molof/pen/WNNMvQE)

Сниппет:

```js
new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 data: () => {
  return {
   box: ['Banana', 'Apple','Coconut']
  }
 },
 methods: {
  action(){
   this.box.shift();
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <ol>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in box" @click="action">
   The index of {{item}} - {{index}}
  </li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Вы неправильно составили метод:
methods:

```
function action(){
}
```

Нужно было:

```
methods: {
    action(){
    }
}
```

И ваш вариант с установки значения переменной тоже не работает. [Прочитайте официальную документацию по VueJS](https://ru.vuejs.org/index.html), документация на русском, вы справитесь.

UPD: Я специально не стал решать вашу проблему, т.к. она изначально неправильно поставлена. В документации есть абзац с предостережением: [ссылка](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

> Из-за ограничений JavaScript, Vue не способен отследить следующие
>   изменения в массиве:
>
> Прямую установку элемента по индексу: `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
>
> Явное изменение длины массива: `vm.items.length = newLength`

Я не буду дублировать полностью документацию Vue, вам просто нужно потратить время на базовые изучения самого фреймворка. В документации все написано про ваш пример с изменением переменной напрямую.